# which is more efficient in sql min or top

Tags: sql, sql-server

which is more efficient in sql min or top?

```
select MIN(salary) from ABC
select top 1 salary from ABC order by salary asc
```

Comment: I imagine it would depend on indexes on the table and the number of rows you have

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: Which more clearly conveys to you what you're trying to do? Does it work? Does it meet your performance goals? If so, move on to the next problem.  Trying to learn billions of little rules for writing "efficient" code and then rigidly applying those rules doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests made on sql server 2012 ( you didn't ask for a specific version, and this is what I have):

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE ABC (salary int)

-- insert sample data
DECLARE @I int = 0

WHILE @i < 1000000 -- that's right, a million records..
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ABC VALUES (@i)
   SET @I = @I + 1
END
```

including execution plans and run both queries:

```
select MIN(salary) from ABC
select top 1 salary from ABC order by salary asc
```

Results:

- Without indexes: query cost for top 1 was 94% and for min was 6%.
- With an index on salary - query cost for both was 50% (doesn't matter if the index is clustered or not).

**Without an index:**
[image: Execution plan without an index]

**With an index:** (clustered and non-clustered resulted in the same execution plan)
[image]

Comment: you can also add a comparison with indexes on the salary column. I believe that should have a similar execution plan

Comment: don't need to, [Evaldas already demonstrated it in his answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29911639/3094533) his answer shows a slight improvement on the top 1 query, but still 90 - 10.

Comment: His plan looks weird, if the index is on salary `TOP 1` should not need to do a `Sort` Operation. I created an index `create index ix_abc_Sal on abc(salary)` on top of your query and the cost for both was exactly the same including the io statistics `Table 'ABC'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0`

Comment: @ughai: I've added a test with a clustered index and a non-clustered index on salary, the results have been added to the answer.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I got as well. It was interesting to see that the costs differ when there is no index and are exactly same when the indexes are in place. + 1

Comment: Thanks Zohar Peled and every one

Comment: glad to help :-) I think that combining the 3 answers to this post will give you a full and complete answer, from both the performance perspective and the code style and readability perspective.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the minimum salary. So use `MIN(salary)`; it is made for exactly this purpose. Your query is thus as readable and maintainable as possible. I have never seen anybody run in performance problems because of using MIN or MAX.

Besides the task to find a minimum in a list is very simple. The task to sort a list (only to keep the first line) is quite another. If you are lucky the DBMS sees through this and doesn't sort at all, but simply looks up the minimum value for you, and then you are where you were with MIN already.

If for some miracle MySQL performs the TOP 1 query faster than the MIN query, then consider this a flaw, stick with the MIN query though, and wait for a future version of MySQL to perform better :-)

Use TOP n queries only when you need more then the MIN or MAX value from the record.

Answer (score 3):

Best way would be looking at execution plans, results may vary of course.

I've tried that on my current environment and `MIN()` seems to work much faster, in first scenario `SORT BY` eats almost everything.
[image: Execution plans]

When using `MIN()` Index scan takes 96% of execution time, which is good.
Table contains around 1bil records.

Comment: Evaldas - Is your index being scanned on the same column as the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Hi - Yes it is. :) I've hidden names for reasons everyone understands.

Comment: Interesting, not sure why would optimizer do a `Sort` operation in the `TOP 1` query if the index being scanned is already sorted. I tried the solution provided by Zohar Peled with an index on salary and the cost for both queries comes out same and there is no `Sort` operation in that execution plan in `TOP 1` query

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand why you've hidden the names. There should be nothing interesting in the names of the tables or indexes. if some hacker was after your data, hiding the table name will not help.

Comment: @ughai why wouldn't it have to do a sort? If you want to get the `TOP 1` lowest value, you have to add `ORDER BY` clause. I've pretty much. I've updated answer with execution plan to contain index names, for you.

Comment: If you have a query with `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY x` and an index on `x`, The data is already sorted based on `x` and the optimizer should not do a physical sort operation when doing a `TOP 1` or a `MIN`. It could just do an `INDEX SCAN` and return the first record it finds in the index.

Comment: Thanks Evaldas Buinauskas and every one