# MSSQL Query get latest value from two tables faster

Tags: sql, t-sql

This query pulls the timestamp (DT_CREATED) from two different tables and selecting the most recent timestamp. The INCIDENT_AUDIT_HISTORY table is quite large and even though I've improved performance by 10 seconds by adding indexes my query still takes over 20 seconds to run, which is longer than desired for the application. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to write this query?

```
    SELECT        i.NUMBER, i.PROBLEM, st.LABEL AS STATUS, i.ID_ASSIGNEE, r.LNAME + ', ' + r.FNAME AS ASIGNEE, c.LNAME + ', ' + c.FNAME AS CUST_NAME, 
                     p.LABEL AS PRIORITY, i.DT_CREATED,
                         (SELECT        MAX(DT_CREATED) AS LAST_WORK
                           FROM            (SELECT        TOP (1) DT_CREATED
                                                     FROM            dbo.REP_WORK_HISTORY AS b
                                                     WHERE        (i.NUMBER = INCIDENT_NUMBER) AND (ID_OWNER = r.ID)
                                                     ORDER BY DT_CREATED DESC
                                                     UNION
                                                     SELECT        TOP (1) DT_CREATED
                                                     FROM            dbo.INCIDENT_AUDIT_HISTORY AS c
                                                     WHERE        (i.NUMBER = INCIDENT_NUMBER) AND (ID_OWNER = r.ID)
                                                     ORDER BY DT_CREATED DESC) AS a) AS LAST_HISTORY, g.GROUP_NAME FROM            dbo.REPS AS r RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.GROUPS AS g ON r.ID_DEFAULT_GROUP = g.ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.INCIDENTS AS i ON r.ID = i.ID_ASSIGNEE LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.CUSTOMERS AS c ON i.ID_CUSTOMER = c.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo._PRIORITIES AS p ON i.PRIORITY = p.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.INCIDENT_STATUSES AS st ON i.ID_STATUS = st.ID WHERE (st.TYPE <> 2) AND (st.TYPE <> 16)
```

Comment: Can you please give a brief what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: He has correlated subquery that picks max date column from 2 tables

Comment: Do you have index on INCIDENT_AUDIT_HISTORY(INCIDENT_NUMBER,ID_OWNER,DT_CREATED DESC) ?, also the same on the REP_WORK_HISTORY table?

Comment: What's your SQL Server release?

Comment: SQL version is unfortunately 2005. Yes I have verified that I have indexes on the referenced fields in the INCIDENT_AUDIT_HISTORY and REP_WORK_HISTORY tables. I was hoping there was a more efficient way of joining the required data that would improve response time.

Comment: If you don't have an index on `DT_CREATED` for tables `INCIDENT_AUDIT_HISTORY` and `REP_WORK_HISTORY` , You should use `MAX(DT_CREATED)` in your inner queries instead of `top 1`. [it should perform better.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911369/which-is-more-efficient-in-sql-min-or-top/29911667#29911667)